# is it "mice infested" or "mouse infested"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, compounds, attributive-nouns, compound-adjectives

You would say "rat infested" but would you say "mouse infested" or "mice infested"?

Sidenote: I think we would say "mouse infestation" so I'm assuming we would also say "louse infestation" as opposed to "lice infestation" as well.

Comment: If there were a bunch of houses on a street throwing a yard sale, it would still be a "yard sale", as opposed to a "yards sale". Similarly, a coin-operated machine does not become "coins-operated" when it requires more than one coin. Further, a "cylinder engine" does not become "cylinders engine" for having more than one cylinder.

Comment: yes, but those are all regulars.  When the plural is irregular (goose geese) then it would go into plural form, i suppose.  People eater as opposed to person eater.

Comment: Hmm. People is a peculiar one, but what about "mouse trap" rather than "mice trap"? Also, why is it then "wild goose chase" instead of "wild geese chase"? I mean, if you were chasing the things, there would probably be more than one. Personally, I would be more afraid they would be chasing me.

Comment: I think this only applies to participle adjectives on nouns with irregular plurals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both forms are acceptable and they are both used according to Google books:

> - While ***[mice-infested](https://books.google.it/books?id=xm0isUzM_iIC&pg=PA490&dq=%22mice%20infested%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC7Oj_q8XJAhWBPQ8KHQ3fAToQ6AEITDAG#v=onepage&q=%22mice%20infested%22&f=false)***  is undoubtedly accepted and used by some speakers, it seems that most speakers still prefer to stick to the stem-form modifier and say mouse-infested.

(The Handbook of English Linguistics
 By  Bas Aarts,April McMahon)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mice%20infested%2C%20mouse%20infested%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmice%20infested%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmouse%20infested%3B%2Cc0) ***mice-infested*** vs ***mouse-infested***

Comment: And note the use of the hyphen to make it a compound word.

Comment: Hyphenated when used as a preceding adjective (mouse-infested barn), but usually not (or not necessarily) otherwise (the barn was mouse infested).

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast 'Particle board' is as much a compound noun as 'ink-well' and 'inkwell'.